# Python subprocess call with greater sign (>) not working

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a executable that accepts string and outputs another string. Now I need to feed a file to it as input and write output to another file. The standard command for that is like the following `executable_path < input > output`. Now I wrap this in python. But I get errors.

```
 cmd = [executable_path , '<', 'tmp/input.txt', '>',
           'tmp/output.txt']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    p.communicate()
```

> invalid argument: <

I also tried joining the cmd arguments:

```
cmd = [executable_path, ' '.join(['<', 'tmp/input.txt', '>',
       'tmp/output.txt'])]
```

> invalid argument: < tmp/input.txt > tmp/output.txt

Passing the command as string didn't work either.

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(cmd))
```

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) has three parameters for easy redirection: `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. By default the subprocess retains the file descriptors of your Python instance.

```
with open('tmp/input.txt', 'rb', 0) as in_stream, \
     open('tmp/output.txt', 'wb', 0) as out_stream:
    subprocess.Popen([executable_path], stdin=in_stream, stdout=out_stream)
```

does the same as the shell command `executable_path < tmp/input.txt > tmp/output.txt`.

The arguments to [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) are the filename, mode and buffering. "rb" means "read binary data", "wb" means "(over)write binary data", "ab" means "append binary data".

Comment: This sounds more neat than what I originally had. I switched to this solution. Thanks.

Comment: You can really use any kind of file descriptor, e.g. pipes, and even TCP [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.fileno).

Comment: @user292139: unrelated: 1. don't use `.communicate()` unless you use `PIPE`. You could use `subprocess.check_call([executable_path], stdin=in_stream, stdout=out_stream)` instead. 2. You can't use TCP sockets here, to redirect subprocess' output on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Redirects (`<`, `>`) are interpreted by shell. You need to specify `shell=True` to use them.

```
cmd = [executable_path , '<', 'tmp/input.txt', '>', 'tmp/output.txt']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: This is not a job for `shell=True`. Use the parameters `stdin` and `stdout` of `Popen()` instead.